# Netty, problems with custom handler for HTTP PUT requests "cannot send more responses than requests"

Tags: java, netty

I am working on a Netty server, I am having issues with a custom handler I created to receive file uploads via HTTP PUT requests. Everything seems to work fine when I just send a few files at a time, however after about 300 connections the server seems to "break". The server will then throw the follow exception on each received request. After this starts happening, the server no longer handles the requests and needs to be restarted:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot send more responses than requests
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentEncoder.writeRequested(HttpContentEncoder.java:104)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.execution.ExecutionHandler.handleDownstream(ExecutionHandler.java:165)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:605)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:572)
....
```

Here is my handler source channelRecieved, all the requests i'm handling are chunked, so I will include those methods below:

```
@Override
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext context, MessageEvent event) throws Exception {
    try {
        log.trace("Message recieved");
        if (newMessage) {
            log.trace("New message");
            HttpRequest request = (HttpRequest) event.getMessage();
            setDestinationFile(context, request);
            newMessage = false;
            if (request.isChunked()) {
                log.trace("Chunked request, set readingChunks true and create byte buffer");
                requestContentStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                readingChunks = true;
                return;
            } else {
                log.trace("Request not chunked");
                writeNonChunkedFile(request);
                requestComplete(event);
                return;
            }
        } else if (readingChunks){
            log.trace("Reading chunks");
            HttpChunk chunk = (HttpChunk) event.getMessage();
            if (chunk.isLast()) {
                log.trace("Read last chunk");
                readingChunks = false;
                writeChunkedFile();
                requestComplete(event);
                return;
            } else {
                log.trace("Buffering chunk content to byte buffer");
                requestContentStream.write(chunk.getContent().array());
                return;
            }
            // should not happen
        } else {
            log.error("Error handling of MessageEvent, expecting a new message or a chunk from a previous message");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Exception: [" + ex + "]");
        sendError(context, INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

This is how I am writing the chunked requests:

```
private void writeChunkedFile() throws IOException {
    log.trace("Writing chunked file");
    byte[] data = requestContentStream.toByteArray();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);
    fos.write(data);
    fos.close();
    log.debug("File upload complete, [chunked], path: [" + destinationFile.getAbsolutePath() + "] size: [" + destinationFile.length() + "] bytes");
}
```

This is how I send the response and close the connection:

```
private void requestComplete(MessageEvent event) {
    log.trace("Request complete");
    HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, OK);
    Channel channel = event.getChannel();
    ChannelFuture cf = channel.write(response);
    cf.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
}
```

I have tried a few things in requestComplete, one being just channel.close() which didn't seem to help. Any other thoughts or ideas?

Here is my pipeline:

```
@Override
public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
    final ChannelPipeline pipeline = pipeline();
    pipeline.addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder());
    pipeline.addLast("encoder", new HttpResponseEncoder());
    pipeline.addLast("deflater", new HttpContentCompressor());
    pipeline.addLast("ExecutionHandler", executionHandler);
```

pipeline.addLast("handler", new FileUploadHandler());
        return pipeline;
    }

Thanks for any thoughts or ideas

Edit: sample log entry when logging between deflator and handler in pipeline:

```
2012-03-23T07:46:40.993 [New I/O server worker #1-6] WARN  NbEvents [c.c.c.r.d.l.s.h.SbApiMessageLogger.writeRequested] [] - Sending [DefaultHttpResponse(chunked: false)
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue]
2012-03-23T07:46:40.995 [New I/O server worker #1-6] WARN  NbEvents [c.c.c.r.d.l.s.h.SbApiMessageLogger.writeRequested] [] - Sending [DefaultHttpResponse(chunked: false)
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8]
2012-03-23T07:46:41.000 [New I/O server worker #1-7] DEBUG NbEvents [c.c.c.r.d.l.s.h.SbApiMessageLogger.messageReceived] [] - Received [PUT /a/deeper/path/testFile.txt HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.12.9.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.2.2
Host: 192.168.0.1:8080
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 256000
Expect: 100-continue
```

Comment: Somethin not related to the problem but adding the ExectionHandler at the end of the ChannelPipeline does not give you any advances. The ExecutionHandler will only work for the ChannelHandlers that are behind it in the ChannelPipeline

Comment: How do you add the HttpContentEncoder to the ChannelPipeline ? I don't see it in your code ? Do you share an instance by any chance ?

Comment: Thanks, I updated my pipline so that   pipeline.addLast("handler", new FileUploadHandler()); comes after the executionHandler. As for the HttpContentEncoder I am not using that anywhere in my code, do I need to be? I thought response encoding was handled by HttpResponseEncoder().

Comment: I also tried adding  pipeline.addLast("chunkedWriter", new ChunkedWriteHandler());. I still have the same problem using the ChunkedWriteHandler, however the exception on the server is now different: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
 at org.jboss.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler.discard(ChunkedWriteHandler.java:171)

Comment: HttpContentCompressor is a sub class of HttpContentEncoder, thats how HttpContentEncoder was added to the pipeline?, HttpContentEncoder has state which only allows to send one response for one request received (HTTP_CONTINUE is excluded), any handler is sending more than one response for a request at a time? What executionHandler does in the pipeline?

Comment: I would simply add a org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHander in between deflater and executionhandler to find out what  HttpResponse is causing this exception.

Comment: Thanks Jestan, I don't think any handler is sending more than one response, if it is it's not my intention. I am only using what's defined above in the pipeline, my custom handler, FileUploadHandler, does send a response but it should only be happening when the request has completed (see method requestComplete in above example). Also I did NOT have handling for HTTP CONTINUE in any of my code, I did try adding htat into my handler using is 100ContinueExpected and then sending back a continue but that seemed to create more problems. With a continue response I cant even upload 1 file

Comment: I added a logging handler between deflator and the execution handler, it shows me the log message. I added a sample entry from the log above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a problem with my implementation, not related to any of the code posted here, the logic posted here seems sound and works fine. That said, many thanks to all for the helpful comments!

Comment: It would be helpful to others seeing the same error to post something about what problem you discovered w/ your implementation.